# DiffUtil for multiple instances of the same list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with elements updated via WebSocket. The update can affect several elements of the list in different places. I'd like to used [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) to update elements of the RecycleView. The socket update itself doesn't contain the whole list element structure but just a few fields.  So in order to update I need get the current data list from the adapter, look up for a elements that needs to be updated, update the fields and pass the new list into DiffUtils to compare with the current one. The problem is that when I update object it also automatically updates in a RecyclerView adapter because it's kept as a reference. So when I get the update from WebSocket I already don't have an "old" list to be compared with updated one.

Comment: use [android.arch.paging.PagedListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter.html), more [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html#classes)

Comment: please look at this [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter), that library already has an implementation for DiffUtil. So you don't need to save the old list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found solution on Medium. Here it is https://android.jlelse.eu/rxjava-and-immutable-diffcallback-in-android-f4637078b03b